# Get json output from php and mySql query using wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I'm trying to create a php page that should shows me a json output.. I'm in a wordpress website and maybe it's a little bit different to retrive datas from database than in a normal php page. By the way, this is my code:

```
<?php


    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';
    global $wpdb;

    $code = ''; 
    $code=$_REQUEST['code'];

    $timestamp = ''; 
    $timestamp=$_REQUEST['timestamp'];

    $username = ''; 
    $username=$_REQUEST['username'];

    $selectData = "SELECT * FROM protocol_data_list WHERE username = '$current_user->user_login'";
    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();
    $result = $wpdb->query($selectData);

    echo $result; 
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row;
    $row_array['code'] = $row['code'];
    $row_array['timestamp'] = $row['timestamp'];
    $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];

        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }

    $json_response = str_replace('\\/', '/', json_encode(array('item' => $json_response), 128));

    echo $json_response;


?>
```

this kind of code is the one i use always to create a json.. But in wordpress it returns an empty array.. I don't know if something's wrong.

Comment: 1.check your query is returning data 
2 if yes then check in while loop by printing array $row_array
3.print $json_response array to check is data is pushed or not

Comment: Check my edit query..in this way if i stamp $result it return 7... and it's correct because there are 7 records..but seems not enter in the while loop

Comment: $wpdb->last_query  try to get your query and paste in your db and see records 
or use print_r($result) to check is value is avialable in which format

Comment: oook here we are i printed this: echo json_encode($wpdb->last_result); and it returns the datas.